# How to displays data from useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs

There is a component that recieves data from the store.

```
function Details(props: any) {
  let details: any
  const routeParams: any = useParams(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    details = props.victims.find((victim: any) => routeParams.pk == victim.pk)
    console.log(details)
  }, [props.victims])
  
  return(
    <>
      {
        details && Object.keys(details.fields).map((f: string, i: number) => f)
      }
    </>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: appStateType) => {
  return {
    victims: state.victimsReducer.victims,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Details)
```

I need display processed data that generated in `useEffect` hook. But this hook perform after a component was rendered. Thus users see only blank screen.

Please help me display generated in `useEffect`  data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to to use `useEffect` for this, the prop changing will trigger a re-render and you can just filter then:

```
const selectedDetail =  props.victims.find((victim: any) => routeParams.pk == victim.pk)
return(
<>
  {
    selectedDetail && Object.keys(selectedDetail.fields).map((f: string, i: number) => f)
  }
</>
```